# <FORM> posting to <IFRAME> causes pop up window in IE7 only

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, internet-explorer-7

I'm construction a iframe and form with jQuery as such:

```
iframe = $("<iframe>", {name : "foo"});
form = $("<form>", {
  target : $iframe.attr("name"),
  action : "/foobar",
  method : "POST"
}).append($("<input>", {
  type  : "submit",
  name  : "amifully",
  value : "dressed"
}).hide());
$("body").append(iframe).append(form);
form.submit();
```

For some reason, in Chrome/Safari/Firefox/IE8+ it works great but in IE7 it opens the form in a pop up window.

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Why are you using the `target` attribute at all?

Comment: I put a comment below your answer below. But basically, the action is not `/foobar`... it's `http://someotherdomain.com/foobar`... thus ajax doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ahhh! I figured it out! Basically, IE7 freaks out when you try to add `name` attributes to elements with jQuery... you have to create the name in the raw string as such:

```
iframe = $("<iframe name=\"foo\">");
```

It was such a subtle thing! Hope this helps prevent someone else from spending 5 hours scouring the internet for an answer.